# What to Do When HTML5 Spellcheck is Not Implemented in Certain Browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

HTML5 spellcheck works in some browsers and not others. In some corporate environments, HTML5 won't be supported for a while. So, what should we do when it's not supported in a particular browser? Obviously, check to see if it's supported. If it is, let it act naturally. But if it isn't, what should we do? I've found a few JavaScript plugins for spell checking, but nothing that really works like the HTML5 spellcheck and nothing totally JavaScript-based. Meaning, for example, I need to have a PHP page that takes in my text, actually does all the spellchecking and then sends back some stylized HTML that I have to handle. Is there something a little more all-encompassing? Specifically, are there any JavaScript-only spellcheckers or do I always have to include a service?

Comment: I guess teaching people to spell correctly is out of the question...  :P

Comment: If you can show me a jQuery plugin that will teach people to spell, @cHao , then I'll use that instead. I went back and accepted a couple more answers. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check what browser it is and for browsers that do not support native spellchecker, enable the JavaScript spellchecker library.

Here's one that's JavaScript and is very good: http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

Comment: It looks pretty good so far. I'm going to look into it a little bit more.